# Apache Flink Produce Kafka from Csv File

Tags: apache-flink, kafka-producer-api

I want to produce kafka from CSV file but the kafka output is as follows ;

org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStreamSource@28aaa5a7

how can I do it?

My Code ;

```
public static class SimpleStringGenerator implements SourceFunction<String> {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 2174904787118597072L;
        boolean running = true;
        long i = 0;
        @Override
        public void run(SourceContext<String> ctx) throws Exception {



            final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
            DataStream<String> text = env.readTextFile("/home/train/Desktop/yaz/aa/1");

            ctx.collect(String.valueOf(text));
            Thread.sleep(10);

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text` is a DataStream object which represents an unbounded stream of elements (in your code each line in the test file will be a different element) so it is not the actual file contents.

If what you want is to produce these elements to Kafka, you need to initialize a Kafka sink and connect your DataStream object to it.

From Flink docs:

```
DataStream<String> stream = ...;
        
KafkaSink<String> sink = KafkaSink.<String>builder()
        .setBootstrapServers(brokers)
        .setRecordSerializer(KafkaRecordSerializationSchema.builder()
            .setTopic("topic-name")
            .setValueSerializationSchema(new SimpleStringSchema())
            .build()
        )
        .setDeliverGuarantee(DeliveryGuarantee.AT_LEAST_ONCE)
        .build();
        
stream.sinkTo(sink);
```